# RX 480 on Ubuntu 16.04 /w AMDGPU

Tags: amd-graphics

So... I was under the impression that the RX 480's required a newer kernel than what shipped with 16.04, however, one day while messing around I accidentally booted up the stock 4.4 kernel with the Padoka PPA mesa and not only did the RX 480 work, it works awesome. Games are running amazingly well here... Now, on 4.4.0-57 it works perfectly. But on 4.4.0-59 it doesn't work at all, it just goes back to software.

Anyone know what the deal here is? Every place I look claims it won't work unless I grab a kernel from a later version, but it clearly does with -57...

Comment: Are you certain _amdgpu_ is being used with the later kernel version and not _radeon_? Check the output of lsmod to see which one is loaded in the kernel.

Comment: amdgpu               2150400  98 -- that's from lsmod, yup.

Comment: Is this with the open source amdgpu drivers, or the AMD GPU Pro drivers downloaded from their site?

Comment: No, as I said in the question this is with the Padoka PPA mesa version, all open source stuff, no pro drivers etc.